# Insert statement not working with CurrentDB Execute in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I executed the Insert statement twice in the code. The first time the inserts statement is working, but the second time the inserts statement does not work. I wish all the cooperation. Code as below:

```vb
    Private Sub cmdOrder_Click()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, lstID As Integer
    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    If Nz(DCount("[Active]", "tblReview", "[EmpID] = [TempVars]![tmpUserID] And [Active]=-1"), 0) = 0 Then
        dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tblReview(EmpID, Active, Created, Submitted)" & _
                "VALUES (" & [TempVars]![tmpUserID] & " ,-1, Date(), 0)"
        lstID = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)

        'If IsNull(DLookup("ReviewID", "tblReviewDetails", "[EmpID] = " & [TempVars]![tmpUserID] & " And [ReviewID] =" & lstID)) Then
            Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT ActionsAndBehaviors FROM tblReviewItmes WHERE MgtLevel=" & [TempVars]![tmpAccess])
            Do While Not rst.EOF
                dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tblReviewDetails(ReviewID, ReviewItems, EmpID)" & _
                    "VALUES (lstID , rst!ActionsAndBehaviors, [TempVars]![tmpUserID])", dbFailOnError

                    'Debug.Print rst!ActionsAndBehaviors
                rst.MoveNext
            Loop
        'End If

        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats the error you get? Which line of code breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second insert command is incorrect?

```
dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tblReviewDetails(ReviewID, ReviewItems, EmpID)" & _
                    "VALUES (lstID , rst!ActionsAndBehaviors, [TempVars]![tmpUserID])", dbFailOnError
```

should be

```
dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tblReviewDetails(ReviewID, ReviewItems, EmpID)" & _
            "VALUES (" & lstID & " , " & rst!ActionsAndBehaviors ", " & [TempVars]![tmpUserID] & ")", dbFailOnError
```

but please use a `recordset`.`AddNew` method to add new records. Your method is very prone to further errors/ `SQL Injection`

Answer (score 0):

Always add MoveFirst before iteration:

```vb
...
            Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT ActionsAndBehaviors FROM tblReviewItmes WHERE MgtLevel=" & [TempVars]![tmpAccess])
            rst.MoveLast
            rst.MoveFirst
            Do While Not rst.EOF
...
```